# How to clear the keys_zone memory in nginx

Tags: nginx

In Nginx is there a way to clear the keys_zone memory? If run nginx reload instead of nginx restart will it clear the memory and re-build it by reading again from proxy_cache_path?

Also what is the relation between keys_zone memory and proxy_cache_path. If the files in proxy_cache_path is deleted will the keys in keys_zone automatically be cleared?